# Probability of rain given various conditions

Tags: probability, problem-solving

The probability of rain given rain the proceeding day is $.6$
The probability of rain given no rain the proceeding day is $.25$

The probability of rain for Friday is $.75$

What is the probability there will be no rain on at least one day of the weekend **(Sat, Sun)**?

My original thought was that one would need to run through all permutations **(Fri, Sat, Sun)** of raining and not raining then sum the probabilities together.  But this seems like a really long problem.  This was a question on a Udacity video , but aside from walking through all combinations I'm stumped on how to accomplish this.

So, if i used the notation 
$$P(r|r) = .6 , P(r|\sim r) = .25$$
$$P(\sim r|r) = .4 , P(\sim r|\sim r) = .75$$
$$P(Fri) = .75$$

Then you would use these to figure out,

$$\begin{gather}
P(Fri) \times P(\sim Sat) + P(\sim Fri)\times P(\sim Sat) +
P(Fri)\times P(Sat)\times P(\sim Sun) \\
+ P(Fri) \times P(\sim Sat) \times P(\sim Sun)\end{gather}$$

...

Not sure if this is correct or if there is a better way

Comment: You use the word *proceeding*, do you mean to use the word *preceding* instead?  Is it the day *before* that influences the probability or is the day *after*?

Comment: Hint: It is easier to find the probability that it will rain on both Saturday and on Sunday, and subtract this number from $1$. I will leave it to you to figure out _why_ such a calculation makes sense, actually do the necessary computations, and then write up everything neatly as an answer to the question that you post yourself to your own question. I also recommend that you edit your question to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/15941) and use MathJax tp impose your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R_5,R_6,R_7$ be the events that it rains on Friday, Saturday, and Sunday, respectively.
Then the probability you want is
\begin{split}
1-P(R_6,R_7) &= 1-P(R_6,R_7 \vert R_5)P(R_5)-P(R_6,R_7 \vert \sim R_5)P( \sim R_5)\\
&=1-P(R_7 \vert R_6)P(R_6 \vert R_5)P(R_5)-P(R_7 \vert R_6) P(R_6 \vert \sim R_5)P(\sim R_5)
\end{split}
which follows by a conditioning argument.